# Too much data duplication in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, duplicates, norm

I'm new to this whole NOSQL stuff and have recently been intrigued with mongoDB.  I'm creating a new website from scratch and decided to go with MONGODB/NORM (for C#) as my only database.  I've been reading up a lot about how to properly design your document model database and I think for the most part I have my design worked out pretty well.  I'm about 6 months into my new site and I'm starting to see issues with data duplication/sync that I need to deal with over and over again.  From what I read, this is expected in the document model, and for performance it makes sense. I.E. you stick embedded objects into your document so it's fast to read - no joins;    but of course you can't always embed, so mongodb has this concept of a DbReference which is basically analogous to a foreign key in relational DBs.

So here's an example:  I have Users and Events;  both get their own document,  Users attend events, Events have users attendees.  I decided to embed a list of Events with limited data into the User objects.  I embedded a list of Users also into the Event objects as their "attendees".  The problem here is now I have to keep the Users in sync with the list of Users that is also embedded in the Event object.  As I read it,  this seems to be the preferred approach, and the NOSQL way to do things. Retrieval is fast, but the fall-back is when I update the main User document, I need to also go into the Event objects, possibly find all references to that user and update that as well.

So the question I have is, is this a pretty common problem people need to deal with?  How much does this problem have to happen before you start saying "maybe the NOSQL strategy doesn't fit what I'm trying to do here"?   When does the performance advantage of not having to do joins turn into a disadvantage because you're having a hard time keeping data in sync in embedded objects and doing multiple reads to the DB to do so?

Comment: Here's [another question about data redundancy in MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3956756/332100). My answer there suggests using map-reduce output as a cache, rather than a separate caching layer. This may be useful, if you can live with stale data. Note that the freshness of the data depends on how often you run the map-reduce job, e.g. every 15 minutes.

Comment: DBReference is evil, it takes away most of the NoSQL charm

Comment: It has been ten years and this question still remains :)

Answer (score 73):

Well that is the trade off with document stores. You can store in a normalized fashion like any standard RDMS, and you should strive for normalization as much as possible. It's only where its a performance hit that you should break normalization and flatten your data structures. The trade off is read efficiency vs update cost.

Mongo has really efficient indexes which can make normalizing easier like a traditional RDMS (most document stores do not give you this for free which is why Mongo is more of a hybrid instead of a pure document store). Using this, you can make a relation collection between users and events. It's analogous to a surrogate table in a tabular data store. Index the event and user fields and it should be pretty quick and will help you normalize your data better.

I like to plot the efficiency of flatting a structure vs keeping it normalized when it comes to the time it takes me to update a records data vs reading out what I need in a query. You can do it in terms of big O notation but you don't have to be that fancy. Just put some numbers down on paper based on a few use cases with different models for the data and get a good gut feeling about how much works is required.

Basically what I do is first try to predict the probability of how many updates a record will have vs. how often it's read. Then I try to predict what the cost of an update is vs. a read when it's both normalized or flattened (or maybe partially combination of the two I can conceive... lots of optimization options). I can then judge the savings of keeping it flat vs. the cost of building up the data from normalized sources. Once I plotted all the variables, if the savings of keeping it flat saves me a bunch, then I will keep it flat.

A few tips:

- If you require fast lookups to be quick and atomic (perfectly up to date) you may want a favor a solution where you favor flattening over normalization and taking the hit on the update.
- If you require update to be quick, and access immediately then favor normalization.
- If you require fast lookups but don't require perfectly up to date data, consider building out your normalized data in batch jobs (using map/reduce possibly).
- If your queries need to be fast, and updates are rare, and do not necessarily require your update to be accessible immediately or require transaction level locking that it went through 100% of the time (to guarantee your update was written to disk), you can consider writing your updates to a queue processing them in the background. (In this model, you will probably have to deal with conflict resolution and reconciliation later).
- Profile different models. Build out a data query abstraction layer (like an ORM in a way) in your code so you can refactor your data store structure later.

There are lot of other ideas that you can employ. There a lot of great blogs on line that go into it like highscalabilty.org and make sure you understand CAP theorem.

Also consider a caching layer, like Redis or memcache. I will put one of those products in front my data layer. When I query mongo (which is storing everything normalized), I use the data to construct a flattened representation and store it in the cache. When I update the data, I will invalidate any data in the cache that references what I'm updating. (Although you have to take the time it takes to invalidate data and tracking data in the cache that is getting updated into consideration of your scaling factors). Someone once said "The two hardest things in Computer Science are naming things and cache invalidation."

Comment: thanks for the response!  a lot of good insight/advice!    i haven't thought of the user-event relation collection.  and caching will be definitely something i'll have to consider in the future.

Comment: +1 for introducing a surrogate table. This will result in a single place where relations between documents are defined, rather than two. @mike: I'd like to point out that [DBRef](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+References#DatabaseReferences-DBRef) is just a formal specification, it ain't magic like foreign keys :) References have to be maintained manually as well, just like duplicate data. So I wouldn't advise you to 'strive for normalization as much as possible'.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an IList of type UserEvent  property to your User object. You didn't specify much about how your domain model is designed. Check the NoRM group http://groups.google.com/group/norm-mongodb/topics
for examples.