# To what level does MongoDB support ACID?

Tags: mongodb, acid

MongoDB is not a relational database nor does the product follow a relational architecture. But for someone coming from the world of RDBMS, I would like to know to what extent does MongoDB support ACID (Atomocity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability). Or should we not evaluate MongoDB from an ACID perspective?

Answer (score 2):

How I love documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#does-mongodb-support-transactions and this very site: [What does MongoDB not being ACID compliant really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149890/what-does-mongodb-not-being-acid-compliant-really-mean)

There are ways to support transactions in MongoDB and the `go` driver even has transactional queries inbuilt into it now.

Here is a brief example of a two phase commit: http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/perform-two-phase-commits/ more complex queries would require more work.

Basically the implications of MongoDBs ACID compliance can be explained via the doc pages and that question mostly.

It is probably one of the most talked about subjects in MongoDB and a quick Google search will give you more information than we could in an answer here.

Comment: Thanks, i have seen the docs already. my intention was to have a broader discussion based on people experiences. I suspected that my question would be closed, fair enough. :)

Comment: @Rajan Yea it is a good topic to get a "definitive" discussion on, only problem is SO is a Q&A site of a particular flavour :) Literally there is more writing on the topic than I could ever write here. I could probably write an entire dissertation on transactional queries in MongoDB alone forgetting the other parts of ACID! (In fact I came close to writing an essay in another question) But yea your question is more of a forum thread or even an entire website dedicated to it rather than a single question.