# How to perform "all or nothing" operation with mongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, transactions, push, insertion

I need insert some elements in a field array on a document. Well... I know that Mongo has atomic Update.Push... The fact is that I need to do this insertion in many documents. The case is that following (I need insert a roles array for every username):

```
 public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
            foreach (string role in roleNames)
            {
                if (!this.RoleExists(role))
                {
                    throw new ProviderException(String.Format("The role '{0}' was not found.", role));
                }
            }

            //How to guarantee that all users will be updated with roles?
            foreach (string user in usernames)
            {
                var docs = this.users.Update(Query.And(Query.EQ("Username", user),
                    Query.EQ("Applications.Name", this.ApplicationName)), Update.AddToSetEach("Applications.$.Roles", 
                   new BsonArray(roleNames)));
            }
        }
```

Suppose the connection down at moment of "pushing" of roles to third username. I need rollback the previous operations. Any idea?

Comment: [Multi-document transaction](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions/#transactions-api) is introduced starting from MongoDB v4.0+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand about MongoDB, it is not ACID compliant with regards to multiple collections. Now, if you are updating a single collection at a time, you should be good. Otherwise, non-ACID compliance is part of the warning label on the box, if you will.

- [Isolate Sequence of Operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/isolate-sequence-of-operations/)
- [Answer to "What does MongoDB not being ACID compliant really mean?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7150406/275679)

Answer (score -1):

UpdateMany() or updateOne() is not an all-in-one operation because if while carrying out the update in multiple documents and the operation timesout or there is power failure. That update on the document would not be automatically completed. You would need to re-rerun the operation to ensure that it is complete.

That's to say, updateOne() and updateMany() doesn't obey the ACID law of Database which stands for Atomicity,Consistency, Isolation, Durability.

Comment: MongoDB is [atomic on the level of a single document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/#atomicity). `updateOne` is an all-or-nothing operation. On the other hand, the face that MongoDB is not ACID-compliant is already mentioned in the accepted answer.